# Word that means oft-repeated pleasantry

Tags: single-word-requests

You know when someone just repeats a cliché phrase to you? Something like "well that's the way the cookie crumbles" or "a penny saved is a penny earned" or "there's plenty of fish in the sea"?

I know there's a word for a (mostly meaningless) idiom/expression that is repeated *ad nauseam*. Does anyone know what I'm talking about?

I will edit this post further with clarifications if necessary.

EDIT: The word I was looking for (platitude) had meaning more along the lines of "repeated so often it has lost any meaning". Katherine Lockwood picked out the word in the comments below

Comment: you said it already: cliché.

Comment: Yes, please do edit, because the word that first comes to mind to me is cliché, which you use at the beginning of your post.

Comment: Platitude, bromide, potboiler (which I only ever heard my grandmother say) ... the thesaurus is good for these kinds of questions.

Comment: A @Mitch has said, the examples that you have given are *clichés*. To answer the question in your title, oft-repeated pleasantries are known as *politenesses*. However, I cannot find a dictionary definition for the term, so I will not post it as an answer. Perhaps someone else can oblige.

Comment: Platitude! That's what I was thinking of. I think I will try to edit the prompt so that it aims more towards the answer. Apologies for being confusing; I just couldn't think of the word

Comment: If you want to be even more "scathing, withering" in emphasising the meaninglessness, you could call them [***vapidities***.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22vapidities%22)

Comment: @KatherineLockwood - OP wants your word written up as an answer, but forgot to ping you.  Great word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/clich%C3%A9) search on synonyms for "cliché" yields some likely candidates. I plucked out the ones that seem most likely to have the meaning you want:

> bromide, platitude, potboiler (which I have only ever heard my grandmother say).

They each have similar meanings in Merriam-Webster, except **potboiler**, which is a bit different:

> [bromide](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bromide):  a commonplace or hackneyed statement or notion
>
> [platitude](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/platitude): a banal, trite, or stale remark
>
> [potboiler](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/potboiler): a usually inferior work (as of art or literature) produced chiefly for profit

One of these words may meet your needs.